# Breaking sides of equation to prove a probability.

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove that $$P(B \cap C \mid A) = P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A \cap B)$$

So far I have been trying to break the equation down LHS and RHS, but I am having trouble figuring out the right side.

$$LHS : P(B \cap C \mid A) = \frac {P(B \cap C\cap A)}{ P(A)}$$
$$RHS : P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A \cap B) = \frac {P(B \cap A \cap C)}{ P(C)??}$$

Once I have those results, I believe I have use elimination to match both sides.

How do I break the RHS down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
P(B \cap C \mid A)=\frac{P(B \cap C \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}\frac{P(C \cap A \cap B)}{P(A\cap B)}=P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A \cap B)
$$